# Batch failure "numeric constants are decimal, hexadecimal or octal" when performing addition, why does it happen / how do I solve it?

Tags: batch

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set month=%dt:~4,2%
set day=%dt:~6,2%
set /a rday=%day%+470
set /a rmonth+%month%+590
echo %rmonth%
echo %rday%
pause
```

What I am trying to do, is find the day and the month, and add numbers to their value. For the month, I'm adding 590, and for the day, I'm adding 470.

It works fine for the day, but for the month, it does not work, and I receive the error "Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)."

I am by no means a programmer, or knowledgeable in batch. I have found the code for extracting the day and the month on the internet, the only thing I've done myself is the last part, and it does not seem to work properly. I assume there must be a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `01` or `07` would be interpreted as octal number because of leading `0`. It's September and `09` is not a valid octal number.

A workaround could be

```
set /a rmonth+1%month%+490
```

but this looks like an ugly hack. I will gladly upvote another answer with the right solution.

Comment: @Vlad Yes, I think the day will not always work either.

Comment: I tested your solution, and it can work. It ended up with 599, which is a hundred days more than it should, but it's easy to subtract a hundred from the total value and receive the actual value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, while extracting day and month from a date string.
Adding a preceding zero to a `%VALUE%` in the 1..9 range raised the error.

My solution was something like this:

```
rem -- demo starts with a digit less than 10 but more than octal 7
set VALUE=9
rem -- add value to 100
set /a NEWVALUE=%VALUE%+100
rem -- no calculation but string manipulation : strip all but last two digits
set VALUE=%NEWVALUE:~-2%
rem -- digital environments too should be kept clean ;)
set NEWVALUE=
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply [`%` *Modulus* operator](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set month=%dt:~4,2%
set day=%dt:~6,2%
set /a rday=1%day%%%100+470
rem         ↑     ↑↑
set /a rmonth=1%month%%%100+590
rem           ↑       ↑↑
echo %rmonth%
echo %rday%
pause
```

Note that you need to double `%` percent sign in a batch script (read [Escaping Percents](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)):

> The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters
>   and `FOR` parameters.  To treat a percent as a regular character,
>   double it:
>
> ```
> %%
> ```